# Is There Some Stream-Only Way To Determine The Index Of The Max Stream Element?

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a `Stream<Set<Integer>> intSetStream`.

I can do this on it...

```
Set<Integer> theSetWithTheMax = intSetStream.max( (x,y)->{ return Integer.compare( x.size(), y.size() ); } ).get( );
```

...and I get a hold of the `Set<Integer>` that has the highest number of `Integer` elements in it.

That's great. But what I really need to know is, is it the 1st `Set` in that `Stream` that's the max? Or is it the 10th `Set` in the `Stream`? Or the `i`th `Set`? Which one of them has the most elements in it?

So my question is: Is there some way  — *using the Stream API* — that I can determine "*It was the `i`th `Set` in the `Stream` of `Set`s that returned the largest value of them all, for the `Set.size( )` call*"?

The best solution I can think of, is to iterate over the `Stream<Set<Integer>>` (using `intSetStream.iterator()`) and do a hand-rolled `max( )` calculation. But I'm hoping to learn a more `Stream`-y way to go about it; if there is such a thing.

Comment: Streams are generally not designed for operations where the order matters. Do you need both the index and the set or just the index?

Comment: @Bubletan _"Streams are generally not designed for operations where the order matters."_ what do you mean? as far as I know, if there is a defined encounter order then the stream will preserve that.

Comment: @Aominè Yes, that's true. What I meant was that very few of the methods actually care about the order. The API was originally designed in such way that it wouldn't matter whether the stream is running in parallel or not. In Java 9 they added `takeWhile` and `dropWhile` which only work for ordered streams.

Comment: @Bubletan I only need the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to firstly map `Stream<Set<Integer>>` to a `Collection<Integer>` where each element is the size of each `Set<Integer>` and then you can extract what is the largest number of elements given `Stream<Set<Integer>>` and then get the "index" of this set by finding an index of the largest number in the collection of sizes.

Consider following example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class IntSetStreamExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final Stream<Set<Integer>> stream = Stream.of(
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3)),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2)),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5)),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0)),
                new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5)),
                new HashSet<>()
        );

        final List<Integer> result = stream.map(Set::size).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println("List of number of elements in Stream<Set<Integer>>: " + result);

        final int max = Collections.max(result);

        System.out.println("Largest set contains " + max + " elements");

        final int index = result.indexOf(max);

        System.out.println("Index of the largest set: " + index);
    }
}
```

The exemplary output may look like this:

```
List of number of elements in Stream<Set<Integer>>: [3, 2, 5, 1, 6, 0]
Largest set contains 6 elements
Index of the largest set: 4
```

Comment: Thanks Syzmon Stepniak. Cool answer! I do agree with @davidxxx that the `Stream.iterator( )` approach I mentioned in my original question, is probably the most straightforward way to go about something like this. However, the only reason I asked my question is to solidify my grasp of Streams. I'm not asking "*what is the most straighforward way to go about this?*" Sometimes, getting my head around a solution that's "*overkill*", is a good way for me to make some things more concrete for me. So I will accept your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a custom collector:

```
int posOfMax = stream.mapToInt(Set::size)
    .collect(() -> new int[] { 0, -1, -1 },
            (a,i) -> { int pos = a[0]++; if(i>a[2]) { a[1] = pos; a[2] = i; } },
            (a1,a2) -> {
                if(a2[2] > a1[2]) { a1[1] = a1[0]+a2[1]; a1[2] = a2[2]; }
                a1[0] += a2[0];
            })[1];
```

This is the most lightweight solution. Its logic becomes clearer when we use a dedicated class instead of an array:

```
int posOfMax = stream.mapToInt(Set::size)
    .collect(() -> new Object() { int size = 0, pos = -1, max = -1; },
            (o,i) -> { int pos = o.size++; if(i>o.max) { o.pos = pos; o.max = i; } },
            (a,b) -> {
                if(b.max > a.max) { a.pos = a.size+b.pos; a.max = b.max; }
                a.size += b.size;
            }).pos;
```

The state object holds the size, which is simply the number of elements encountered so far, the last encountered max value and its position which we update to the previous value of the size if the current element is bigger than the max value. That’s what the *accumulator* function (the second argument to `collect`) does.

In order to support arbitrary evaluation orders, i.e. parallel stream, we have to provide a *combiner* function (the last argument to `collect`). It merges the state of two partial evaluation into the first state. If the second state’s max value is bigger, we update the first’s max value and the position, whereas we have to add the first state’s size to the second’s position to reflect the fact that both are partial results. Further, we have to update the size to the sum of both sizes.

Comment: Even though @davidxxx's and Syzmon Stepniak's answers are both excellant answers, this is easily the most elegant and most lightweight solution offered so far. I would be surprised if there were another solution that outdid this one on elegance and lowest space cost. This is exactly the kind of "_stream-only_" solution I had in mind in asking the question. If you'd posted it two days earlier, this would have been the accepted answer. A hearty Thanks for such a "_**beautiful**_" answer :)

Comment: I'm dying to know what inspired this solution to occur to you, Holger. Had you seen a similar solution somewhere else? In the Stream API source code itself maybe? Is it simply something that came from advance experience working with Java's Stream API or maybe  previous experience with functional programming idioms in general? Or something as simple as 2 days worth of trial and error and/or reading the best book in the world on the Stream API? Speaking of which. What in your opinion _**is**_ the best book in the world on the Stream API by the way? If one doesn't exist, you should write it ;)

Comment: @deduper you should stay on SO more often... :) Holger's answers are among most appreciated around here, where I work we have an entire package called `xxx.HolgerUtil` - mainly because 1) why not? 2) the things we have there are only possible because of his answers 3) the package documentation starts with "If you think this is a weird class Name, you haven't worked here long enough..."

Comment: There's an interesting coincidence related to Holger's array-based explanation. The `Set<Integer>`s of my OQ started out life as `int[]` representations. The `Set<Integer>`s represent slices of a table as prescribed by a dynamic programming algorithm. The original algo uses an `int[][]` to calculate a maximum number of visitations. As an exercise, I implemented the algorithm using `Stream<Set<Integer>>`s in place of the `int[]` rows. How close is my guess, Holger, that your solution was inspired by some sort or memoization idiom?

Comment: There is an existing builtin collector, [`summarizingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-), which provides the count and maximum (as well as sum and minimum) in one go. From there, it’s only a small step to get the index of the maximum. You may also consider `collect` to be the operation closest to a loop, allowing mutable state, having the *supplier* for the initialization and the *accumulator* performing the loop’s body. The new thing and biggest obstacle is the *combiner* for partial results.

Comment: Awesome! [*I see what you mean*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49875231/4465539). Thanks for the insight :)

Answer (score 1):

Streams methods are not designed to be aware of the current element iterated.
So I think that you actual way : find the Set with the max of elements and then iterate on the Sets to find this Set is not bad.

As alternative you could first collect the `Stream<Set<Integer>>` into a List (to have a way to retrieve the index) and use a `SimpleImmutableEntry` but it seems really overkill :

```
Stream<Set<Integer>> intSetStream = ...;
List<Set<Integer>> list = intSetStream.collect(Collectors.toList());

SimpleImmutableEntry<Integer, Set<Integer>> entry = 
        IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                 .mapToObj(i -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(i, list.get(i)))
                 .max((x, y) -> {
                     return Integer.compare(x.getValue()
                                             .size(),
                                            y.getValue()
                                             .size());
                 })
                 .get();

Integer index = entry.getKey();
Set<Integer> setWithMaxNbElements = entry.getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Insight provided in @Holzer's custom `Collector`-based solution (*on top of my downright shameless plagiarizing of* [*the source code of IntSummaryStatistics.java*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/d9a44cfdeebf/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.java)), inspired a custom `Collector`-based solution of my own; *that might, in turn, inspire others*...

```
public class IndexOfMaxCollector implements IntConsumer {

    private int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private int maxIdx = -1;
    private int currIdx = 0;

    public void accept( int value ){

        if( value > max ) 
            maxIdx = currIdx;

        max = Math.max( max, value );

        currIdx++;
    }

    public void combine( IndexOfMaxCollector other ){

        if( other.max > max ){

            maxIdx = other.maxIdx + currIdx; 

            max = other.max;  
        }

        currIdx += other.currIdx;
    }

    public int getMax( ){ return this.max; }

    public int getIndexOfMax( ){ return this.maxIdx; }
}
```

...Using that custom `Collector`, I could take the `intSetStream` of my OQ and determine the index of the `Set<Integer>` that contains the highest number of elements, like this...

```
int indexOfMax = intSetStream.map( Set::size )
    .collect( IndexOfMaxCollector::new,
              IndexOfMaxCollector::accept,  
              IndexOfMaxCollector::combine )
    .getIndexOfMax( );
```

This solution — admittedly not the most "*beautiful*" — possibly has a teensie bit of an edge over others in both the *reusability* and *understandability* stakes.

Comment: Your `combine` method needs to combine the indices as well (like the combiner in my answer), e.g. `maxIdx = other.max > max? other.maxIdx + currIdx: maxIdx; currIdx += other.currIdx;`.

Comment: Cheers @Holger :) I'll change that in a moment. At the risk of sounding like a numbskull, it's not obvious to me what's being "*combined*" with those expressions you shared. As long as I'm being humble, the "*why*" flew over my head too :) Please elaborate? Thanks :)

Comment: In a multi-threaded context, the *supplier* will be called once per worker thread, to use the returned object with the *accumulator* locally. This is what makes it thread safe; each worker modifies a different object. Once two worker threads have processed their elements, their *partial results* must be merged to a result covering both. In this specific case, each result will start counting by zero, so when using the right result’s index, the left result’s count must be added to it to get an index in the merged range. Further, the counts must be summed up, as the result might get merged again…

Comment: See also [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction)

Comment: Yeah. I did read [*that javadoc*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) as part of my research before implementing my solution. Thanks just the same, though :) But it has to be said, I was obviously still confused even having read the [*the javadoc*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) :) So your explanation really brought it home for me. Thanks again.

Comment: @Holger: "_...the left result’s_ ***count*** _must be added to it_...Further, the ***counts*** _must be summed up_..." — Actually, I'm not tracking a "***count***" per se. But I understand what you mean ("***currIdx***").

Comment: There is no technical difference between counting and your `currIdx`. When doing it right, the final `IndexOfMaxCollector` instance’s `currIdx` field will contain the total count at the end of the operation. It serves the role of a current index in the accumulator function, but at the same time, it serves as a count of all encountered elements in the combiner function. You need the count to adapt the index when merging (and there wouldn’t be much sense to maintain two variables with different names but he same contents, just to name the two roles it serves).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169163/discussion-between-deduper-and-holger).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library:

```java
int index = StreamEx.of(intSetStream)
        .zipWith(IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1))
        .maxBy(e -> e.getKey().size())
        .orElseThrow()
        .getValue();
```

This uses [`StreamEx.zipWith`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#zipWith(java.util.stream.Stream)) to zip the stream with the infinite stream [0, 1, 2, 3, …], producing a `Stream<Map.Entry<Set<Integer>, Integer>>` with `Map.Entry` consisting of the stream element and its index.  It then uses the [`maxBy`](http://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/AbstractStreamEx.html#maxBy(java.util.function.Function)) method to find the `Map.Entry` with the greatest value as an `Optional<Map.Entry>`.  Finally, it returns the value of the entry within the optional, i.e. the index of the maximum entry.