# Advantages/Drawbacks of "var" in Java 10

Tags: java, java-10

AFAIK, `var` is not keyword in **Java**. It is *reserved type name*. I wonder that in what circumstances we should use/avoid it. Are there principles about its usage?

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var x = new HashMap<> (); // legal
        var y = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); // legal

        var z = "soner"; // legal
        System.out.println(z);

        var umm = null;  // xx wrong xx //
        var foo; // xx wrong usage without initializer xx //

        var var = 5; // legal

    }
}
```

Comment: There are many exisiting question here about java-10's var :)

Comment: The short version, this is some syntax sugar to prevent the verbosity of `Map<String, Integer> y = new HashMap<String, Integer>();` basicly. I believe this will be replace during compilation.

Comment: 'var' is about type inference within the same method. From my point of view, I advise not to use it as you lose too much in readability within your code, and this is something that should never happen

Comment: For all that sake, Stuart actually wrote about the practices and [LVTI coding guidelines](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html) which includes a majority of use cases that people would pick up in their answer based on their opinions.

Answer (score 22):

I know one reason, that we actually use in our project. Whenever there is a variable that is "big" we replace it with var. For example:

```
 public void test(){
     CreateEmailEsignTransactionAsync job = new CreateEmailEsignTransactionAsync(... some input);

     // vs 
     var job = new CreateEmailEsignTransactionAsync(... some input)
 }
```

I find the second example a lot more readable, and this is how we mainly use it.

There is another example where this could be used (but I am not using it so far). Previously this was possible via chaining only for lambda expressions for example, as this would be a type known by the compiler only - they could not be declared.

```
 public void test() {
        var test = new Object() {
            public void go() {

            }
        };

        test.go();
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the improvment in readability, especially when the name isn't a good representation of what the var is about. But as I said earlier, it is primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Because having `CreateEmailEsignTransactionAsync job` change something for the rest of the code @DamCx ? An initialisation is required during the declaration with a `var` so the readability is preserved since you always have the constructor type.

Comment: I hadn't thought of using `var` to declare anonymous types like that. That's neat.

Comment: @Strikegently well, if you want something very smart used for this anonymous types, see this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782716/is-there-some-stream-only-way-to-determine-the-index-of-the-max-stream-element/49802582#49802582

Comment: I would second the thought of poor choice of variable name in the examples. Slightly faded in my memory yet I remember a similar line from Stuart in the [LVTI style doc](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/amber/LVTIstyle.html)

Comment: @Arundev you mean to `var`? if so - yes. what is your point?

Comment: @Arundev I really dont get your point here and how is that related to the answer

Comment: The usage of `var` unfortunately also comes with the consequence in many cases, as pointed out in other comments that you *cannot* know the real type of the variable, unless you very carefully use at least 1 or 2 more clicks to search out the type of that method call, that could come from a variety of different libraries, further complicating what the actual type might be. This consequence is further intensified when having to review code through "currently" all available code repository sites such as: github, bitbucket, gitlab, azure devops, the list goes on... hence I favor no use of `var`

Answer (score 21):

I can see one drawback to use `var` aka "*Local type-inference*":

```
var x = "A";
// String x
var y = getInstance(x);
//? y
```

In that context, you need to check the signature of `getInstance(String)` method to know what will be `y` type.

EDIT:

Since there is a discussion about the name of my variables not being really correct, let's use some real example then.

```
 var sDate = "20180426";
 var date = DateUtil.getDate(sDate);
```

What type is `date` ?

I could call

```
 public static java.util.Date getDate(String);
 public static java.sql.Date getDate(String);
 public static java.time.LocalDate getDate(String);
```

I don't believe the solution would be to use a full name either.

```
 var javaUtilDate
 var javaSqllDate
 var javaTimeLocalDate
```

So instead, in that case I would not use type inference

```
var sDate = "20180426";
LocalDate date = DateUtil.getDate(sDate);
```

*Note: Can someone tell me if this require the import of `LocalDate` if I use `var` (note that I use a method in a different class, so I never had to declare `LocalDate` in this class).

I will answer myself if I find the time to install a JDK10.*

Comment: Don't call it `y` then. ;)

Comment: To be fair, even if it's called `instance`, it wouldn't tell much about the type of the variable...

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat It should be named whatever be the return type of `getInstance` is for `x` in that case.

Comment: This is off course using bad names on purpose @Nicolai. Best example then, if I call that `date`, will it be a `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date` or even a `java.time.LocalDate`. I always call those `date` with some prefix/postfix based on the need.

Comment: I have added an example of a correct name but still pointing at the problem @nullpointer.

Comment: You got a point here. This is clearly one drawback of var. In this case using var probably won't be a good choice

Comment: I disagree this is a drawback if one is using a modern IDE. For example, IntelliJ (is by default configured) shows the typed that was inferred embedded in a code highlight. That can be turned off. However, I find the reducing in code noise and boilerplate to far outweigh the possibility someone has ill-named or misnamed the variables. I would refactor the poor naming to improve it.

Comment: In developing enterprise level software, the usage of `var` does introduce far more noise than simply declaring the type, as you have to lookup and look back into methods far too much, losing your train of thoughts inspecting said code. This becomes more severe when having to do code review in a 100k+ project

Answer (score 4):

You could use it for anonymous classes too, i.e. there is just no type to declare. E.g.

```
var r = new Runnable()
{
  int result1, result2;
  @Override public void run()
  {
    result1 = doStuff();
    result2 = doMoreStuff();
  }
}

makeSomething(r);
System.out.println(r.result1 * r.result2);
```